# Different error between port 80 and 5500 when running site

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, localhost, hosting

I'm working on a chat bot system. Every time I write a message and expect a message back, I get an error message.

The weird part is that the error message depends whether I run the site on localhost port 80 or 5500. Another thing is that localhost:5500 doesn't require an Apache server but port 80 (localhost) does.

If I run it on localhost (port 80), I get the

> POST http://localhost/get-response/ 404 (Not Found)

If I run it on localhost:5500 I get

> POST http://localhost:5500/get-response/ 405 (Method Not Allowed)

chatbot.js

```
            fetch("/get-response/", {   //<--- error
                    body: JSON.stringify({'message': message['text']}),
                    cache: 'no-cache', 
                    credentials: 'same-origin', 
                    headers: {
                        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/4.0 MDN Example',
                        'content-type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    method: 'POST',
                    mode: 'cors', 
                    redirect: 'follow',
                    referrer: 'no-referrer',
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json()).then((json) => {
                        this.messages.push(json['message'])
                    })
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('', Index),
    path('get-response/', get_response),
]
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_response(request):
    response = {'status': None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        message = data['message']

        chat_response = chatbot.get_response(message).text
        response['message'] = {'text': chat_response, 'user': False, 'chat_bot': True}
        response['status'] = 'ok'

    else:
        response['error'] = 'no post data found'

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response),
            content_type="application/json"
        )

def Index (request):
    context = {'title': 'Chatbot Version 1.0'}

    return render(request, "AI.html", context)
```

How do I know which error message to go for?

Comment: how do you run on port 80?, what command you use to runserver on port 80

Comment: @ShubhamDevgan I don't use commands to run the site. I use localhost. The weird part is that localhost:5500 doesn't require Apache server but port 80 does.

Comment: that is because ports below 1024 are reserved for system apps or by other applications, so in your case or in general case , if you have a server installed it will run on port 80, so you'll need apache to run on port 80. @John.P

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function as a API view so, It should be mentioned in the method decorator like shown below

```
 from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
 @csrf_exempt
 @api_view(['POST'])
 def get_response(request):
      .....
    your code
      .....
```

Hope it will give you the solution.

more than one HTTP methods can be used like shown here.

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
```

And if you want to run server on port 80, Then it should be mentioned in the command like shown below.

```
 python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:80
```

127.0.0.1 means the localhost

python manage.py runserver will take port number 8000

Answer (score 0):

you need to allow api methods for you view like this :

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['POST'])
@csrf_exempt
def get_response(request):
    response = {'status': None}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        message = data['message']

        chat_response = chatbot.get_response(message).text
        response['message'] = {'text': chat_response, 'user': False, 'chat_bot': True}
        response['status'] = 'ok'

    else:
        response['error'] = 'no post data found'

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response),
            content_type="application/json"
        )
```